# input css not working

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, fonts

I have created a page using JSF 2.0. Below is what I have

```
<h:dataTable id="patentDetailsList" value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.getAllPatentInfo()}"
             var="patentInfo" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="8" cellpadding="5"
             cellspacing="3" width="100%">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Patent Information" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ID" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentInfo.personalInfoId}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandLink value="#{patentInfo.fullName}" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.takeMeToAnotherPage('patentss')}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.personalInfoId}" value="#{patentInfo.personalInfoId}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Email ID" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentInfo.emailID}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Mobile Number" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patentInfo.mobileNumber}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Action" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.setEditPersonalInfo()}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit?')">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.personalInfoId}" value="#{patentInfo.personalInfoId}" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.deletePersonalInfo()}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.personalInfoId}" value="#{patentInfo.personalInfoId}" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
</dataTable>
```

In css, I have

```
body {
    font-family: verdana, 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 15px;
}

a {
    font-family: verdana, 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 15px;
}

input {
    font-family: verdana, 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

What is making MAD is, font and size are getting applied to all text and link **EXCEPT buttons**. Edit and Delete buttons are not coming as others are coming.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

***I know*** using `styleClass` I could have done that, however if I do it using `styleClass` I will have to write everyplace which is MORE work.

### Update 1

Generated HTML is

```
<table id="patentDetailsList" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="8" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr><th colspan="5" scope="colgroup">Patent Information</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Mobile Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt65'),{'patentDetailsList:0:j_idt71':'patentDetailsList:0:j_idt71'},'');return false">Fahim Parkar</a></td>
        <td>parkarfahim22@yahoo.co.in</td>
        <td>66991234</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:0:j_idt75" value="Edit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit?')" /><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:0:j_idt76" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt65'),{'patentDetailsList:1:j_idt71':'patentDetailsList:1:j_idt71'},'');return false">Fahad Parkar</a></td>
        <td>parkarfahad7@gmail.com</td>
        <td>88888888</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:1:j_idt75" value="Edit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit?')" /><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:1:j_idt76" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt65'),{'patentDetailsList:2:j_idt71':'patentDetailsList:2:j_idt71'},'');return false">Patent First</a></td>
        <td>patent@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>66991234</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:2:j_idt75" value="Edit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit?')" /><input type="submit" name="patentDetailsList:2:j_idt76" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show the generated HTML.

Comment: use this input[type=button] {/*CSS goes here*/}

Comment: try applying a similar rule to `button` elements, as the *edit* / *delete* buttons may render to these.

Comment: @Mr.Alien you're not viewing the generated HTML, but an abstraction as the declarative syntax of JSF.

Comment: @EliranMalka I noticed, sorry :)

Comment: try this input[type=submit] {/*CSS Goes Here*/}

Comment: @Mr.Alien : What if I **also** need to apply the same for type=text

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bpJd5/

Comment: @Mr.Alien : it is working, however I also need to apply to text and textArea too

Comment: @NikolaK. : I know what way its working, however due to JSF it is not working...

Comment: @FahimParkar you can read my answer

Comment: @FahimParkar your code is fine for the html you posted, but as I state in my answer, there seems to be greater forces at work, like a more specific css rule (in some css file or even in-line in the html) so your input style definition is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
input[type=submit] {
/*Your CSS Goes Here*/
}

/*For text+submit*/
input[type=submit], input[type=text] {
/*Your CSS Goes Here*/
}

/*For Textarea*/

textarea {  /*For All Text Area*/
/* CSS Goes Here */
}

textarea.only_one_textarea {  /*This will apply to thextarea with class .only_one_textarea. See ref 1*/
/* CSS Goes Here */
}

<!--Ref 1-->
<textarea class="only_one_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: input[type=submit], input[type=text], input[type=file], input[type=textArea] {.... } did the trick... thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but there seems to be a CSS rule in action that is more specific than your definition.
This is a bit of a hacky solution, but might work.

```css
#patentDetailsList input[type="submit"],
#patentDetailsList input[type="text"],
#patentDetailsList textarea{
    font-family: verdana, 'Times New Roman';
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

The important part is the overly specific selector. 
You could also try the following selectors:

```css
form input
#patentDetailsList input[type="submit"]
#patentDetailsList input
form table#patentDetailsList input[type="submit"]
```

this is not a definitive solution but might work, if it doesn't, you could post the other css that is being generated for the page, and/or the whole dom tree for this table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 247px; height: 88px; overflow: hidden; -webkit-user-select: none; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171); "></div>
```